# WiX Shell Command Conditional Installation

Tags: wix

I'm new to WiX (and Windows development in general), and I'd like to add logic to my installer that will cause the installation to fail with a friendly error if the shell command fails. I've seen the [ShellExecute CustomAction](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/shellexec.html) and instructions for [Conditional Installation](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/getting-started/conditional-installation), but I'm not sure how to tie these together.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to write my own Custom Action in either VbScript or C# while calling API method ShellExecute. In this way, we have good control over its return code (if ShellExecute fails) and we can display our own user friend message and terminate the installation (or set it to roll back).

Here is an example not specific to ShellExecute, but how to quit from Installation while showing your own user friend message:

http://devdare.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-quit-installation-from-vbscript.html

For using ShellExecute in VBScript Custom Action:
http://ss64.com/vb/shellexecute.html

Hope this helps.